# Inherit class array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the first picture is my parent class:

[image]

All it does is set header to "default header" and make new array of type `LevelData`. When I call `Setup()`, the overridden child method is called as I want it to. In the child class on `Setup()` method when I print header it says "default header" as should. When I print length of the array it says 10 as it should.

But when I try to access the array I get an Object reference error. Why can I access the header and the length of the array but not the array itself?

Here is the child:

[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Delete the images and post the actual code. You can highlight it and press the `{ }` in the toolbar to fix the formatting if it does not look correct.

Comment: Please paste your code **as text**, not as images.

Comment: Did someone already mention to not insert the code as images?

Comment: your array is initialized, but the items in the array are all null

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array, all array elements are initialized to `default(T)` where `T` is the element type. For reference types (a class is a reference type), this is always `null`. `string` is a reference type as well. For numeric types `default(T)` is always the value `0`. All other types are initialized with all bits set to `0`.

If you want the array to contain elements, you must initialize each entry:

```
for (int i = 0; i < levels.Length; i++) {
    levels[i] = new LevelData();
}
```

Note that a class might not have a default constructor, i.e. a constructor with no parameters. A class might have no public constructor at all and be instantiatable only through a factory method. How should the array be initialized automatically with non null entries then?

See: [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)